# How to get a matrix row conditionally?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab I have a variable X containing training data (rowwise). Additionally there is a variable S with the class of the data. How to get all entries of X with a specific (e.g. negative) class ?

Example:

```
X = [1 2;3 4;5 6;7 8;9 10];
S = [1 -1 -1 1 -1];
```

Should give:

```
ans = [3 4;5 6;9 10];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to do:

```
X(S<0,:)
```

This array will contain the rows of `X` for which `S` is negative.

Best

Comment: @JHnet Please accept the answer if it works for you.